# php - split by unknown regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I need to split a string by seperators that are known to me and also unknown.
For example i know i want to split the string by "\n" and "," and "." but also 1 sperator that can be user defined: for example it can be ";" or "hello" or pretty much anything.

I tried this:

```
"[\n|,|.|".$exp."]"
```

...but that didnt work as expected. As i understand | means or. So this reg exp should say that split by "\n" or "," or "." or "hello". 
I think its because if i try just [hello] then it splits by every letter, not the whole word. Thats strange because if i try just [\n] then it only splits by "\n" - not by "\" or "n".

Can someone please explain this to me? :)

Comment: the brackets is used to define a list of character, [ab] is a or b, it is the same as a|b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you place a bunch of characters in a character class, as in `[hello]`, this defines a token that matches one character that is either h, e, l or o. Also, `|` has no meaning inside of a character class - it's just matched as a normal character.

The correct solution isn't to use a character class - you meant to use normal brackets:

`(\n|,|\.|".$exp.")`

By the way - make sure that you escape any regex metacharacters that are in `$exp`. Basically, the full list here needs to be escaped with backslashes: http://regular-expressions.info/reference.html There may be a helper function to do it for you.

EDIT: Since you're not using a character class, we now need to escape `\` the `.` which is now a metacharacter meaning 'match one of anything'. Almost forgot.

Comment: Got it, Thank you and everyone else who anwsered :)

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is actually only one character, a new line, (the `\` before the `n` indicates an escape sequence) so that's why it works and `hello` doesn't.

Also, keep in mind that allowing arbitrary input into a regular expression can be a security risk, depending on what your regular expression is being used for, so be very careful and make sure you sanitize your input to that regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex:

```
preg_split('#[\n,.]|'.$exp.'#', ...);
```

Note the single quots, to avoid `\n` getting replaced by the new line.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `[` and `]` as these define a character class.  `\n` counts as a single character in a double-quoted string.  Just using the string without the character class should work as you need:

```
preg_split("/\n|,|.|$exp/", $input)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_split()

For example:

Input:

```
$exp = '#';
preg_split("/[,.\n$exp]/", "0\n1,2.3#4")
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple solution:

```
"(\n|,|\.|".$exp.")"
```

or you can do it like:

```
"([\n,.]|".$exp.")"
```

Comment: You have it backwards, you need to escape `.` when it's outside of a character class and not when it is.

Comment: didn't notice that.. fixed